# VSOMEIP - Communication between 2 devices (TCP/UDP) Not working

Tags: c++, ubuntu, tcp, udp, automotive

Following the VSOMEIP tutorial [Vsomeip in 10 minutes](https://github.com/GENIVI/vsomeip/wiki/vsomeip-in-10-minutes) everything works up to the point of [Communication between 2 devices](https://github.com/GENIVI/vsomeip/wiki/vsomeip-in-10-minutes#devices).

Current Setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04 (two machines - Server & Client)
- Two Machines connected over ethernet

Files used:

- server.cpp
- client.cpp
- client_config.json
- server_config.json

**Output of Server**

```html
[info] Parsed vsomeip configuration in 1ms
[info] Using configuration file: "../clie_prop.json".
[info] Default configuration module loaded.
[info] Initializing vsomeip application "Hello".
[info] SOME/IP client identifier configured. Using 0033 (was: 1313)
[info] Instantiating routing manager [Proxy].
[info] Client [33] is connecting to [0] at /tmp/vsomeip-0
[info] Listening at /tmp/vsomeip-33
[info] Application(Hello, 33) is initialized (11, 100).
[info] Starting vsomeip application "Hello" using 2 threads
[warning] local_client_endpoint::connect: Couldn't connect to: /tmp/vsomeip-0 (Connection refused / 111)
[info] io thread id from application: 0033 (Hello) is: 7f80f5cd88c0 TID: 1497
[info] routing_manager_proxy::on_disconnect: Client 0x33 calling host_->on_state with DEREGISTERED
[info] io thread id from application: 0033 (Hello) is: 7f80f15e7700 TID: 1501
[info] shutdown thread id from application: 0033 (Hello) is: 7f80f1de8700 TID: 1500
[info] main dispatch thread id from application: 0033 (Hello) is: 7f80f25e9700 TID: 1499
[warning] local_client_endpoint::connect: Couldn't connect to: /tmp/vsomeip-0 (Connection refused / 111)
[info] routing_manager_proxy::on_disconnect: Client 0x33 calling host_->on_state with DEREGISTERED
[warning] local_client_endpoint::connect: Couldn't connect to: /tmp/vsomeip-0 (Connection refused / 111)
[info] routing_manager_proxy::on_disconnect: Client 0x33 calling host_->on_state with DEREGISTERED
[warning] local_client_endpoint::connect: Couldn't connect to: /tmp/vsomeip-0 (Connection refused / 111)
[info] routing_manager_proxy::on_disconnect: Client 0x33 calling host_->on_state with DEREGISTERED
[warning] local_client_endpoint::connect: Couldn't connect to: /tmp/vsomeip-0 (Connection refused / 111)
[info] routing_manager_proxy::on_disconnect: Client 0x33 calling host_->on_state with DEREGISTERED
[warning] local_client_endpoint::connect: Couldn't connect to: /tmp/vsomeip-0 (Connection refused / 111)
[info] routing_manager_proxy::on_disconnect: Client 0x33 calling host_->on_state with DEREGISTERED
```

**Output of Client**

```html
[info] Parsed vsomeip configuration in 0ms
[info] Using configuration file: "../serv_prop.json".
[info] Default configuration module loaded.
[info] Initializing vsomeip application "World".
[warning] Routing Manager seems to be inactive. Taking over...
[info] SOME/IP client identifier configured. Using 1212 (was: 1212)
[info] Instantiating routing manager [Host].
[info] init_routing_endpoint Routing endpoint at /tmp/vsomeip-0
[info] Client [1212] is connecting to [0] at /tmp/vsomeip-0
[info] Service Discovery enabled. Trying to load module.
[info] Service Discovery module loaded.
[info] Application(World, 1212) is initialized (11, 100).
[info] OFFER(1212): [1234.5678:0.0]
[info] Starting vsomeip application "World" using 2 threads
[info] Watchdog is disabled!
[info] io thread id from application: 1212 (World) is: 7fa68723d8c0 TID: 5370
[info] Network interface "enp0s3" state changed: up
[info] vSomeIP 2.10.21 | (default)
[info] Sent READY to systemd watchdog
[info] io thread id from application: 1212 (World) is: 7fa6828f3700 TID: 5374
[info] shutdown thread id from application: 1212 (World) is: 7fa6838f5700 TID: 5372
[info] main dispatch thread id from application: 1212 (World) is: 7fa6840f6700 TID: 5371
[warning] Releasing client identifier 0003. Its corresponding application went offline while no routing manager was running.
[info] Application/Client 0003 is deregistering.
```

All the code used is the same as the code used in [Request/Response](https://github.com/GENIVI/vsomeip/wiki/vsomeip-in-10-minutes#request) in the vsomeip tutorial. The **config files** are the same as the config file specified in the [communication between 2 devices](https://github.com/GENIVI/vsomeip/wiki/vsomeip-in-10-minutes#devices) section **with the IP Addresses changed to match my machine addresses**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution!!

If you navigate to the **/build/examples** folder in the *vsomeip or vsomeip-master* directory, you will find executables (response-sample, subscribe-sample, etc.). If you run them in such a way that they use the same configuration files as used in the **vsomeip in 10 mintutes** (changing unicast addresses, etc.) it should work perfectly. 
**This is the configuration file I used.**

```html
{
    "unicast" : "192.168.43.6",
    "logging" :
    {
        "level" : "debug",
        "console" : "true",
        "file" : { "enable" : "false", "path" : "/tmp/vsomeip.log" },
        "dlt" : "false"
    },
    "applications" :
    [
        {
            "name" : "World",
            "id" : "0x1212"
        }
    ],
    "services" :
    [
        {
            "service" : "0x1234",
            "instance" : "0x5678",
            "unreliable" : "30509"
        }
    ],
    "routing" : "World",
    "service-discovery" :
    {
        "enable" : "true",
        "multicast" : "224.224.224.245",
        "port" : "30490",
        "protocol" : "udp",
        "initial_delay_min" : "10",
        "initial_delay_max" : "100",
        "repetitions_base_delay" : "200",
        "repetitions_max" : "3",
        "ttl" : "3",
        "cyclic_offer_delay" : "2000",
        "request_response_delay" : "1500"
    }
}
```

I used shell script to do this.

```html
#!/bin/bash
route add -host 224.224.224.245 dev <interface>
export VSOMEIP_CONFIGURATION=<config_file>
export VSOMEIP_APPLICATION_NAME=<application_name>
./<executable>
```

It did for me anyways! Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Rob Crowley's answer, I got it working using the two unique .json configuration files included in the "vsomeip in 10 minutes" tutorial. I used the "World" configuration on the host offering the service and the "Hello" configuration file on the host running the client. The only thing I need to modify in these files was the "unicast" address. I changed that to match the IP address of the respective hosts.

I also modified the script to use "sudo" before the "route add -host" command, as I found it wouldn't actually add the route without it.

I called make in the "vsomeip/build/examples/" folder to build the examples. The  I pointed to on the script for the service service was "notify-sample" executable (vsomeip/build/examples/). The  I pointed to on the script for the service service was "subscribe-sample" executable (vsomeip/build/examples/).

This combination worked for me after connecting my two hosts via ethernet and ensuring their IP addresses matched those in the "unicast" field of their respective configuration files.